# Salesforce image resize in LWC

Tags: css, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lightning

I am new to salesforce development. I want to display an image in LWC in salesforce. I added the image in static resource and add the line in lightning component

```
<img src="{Resource.Img1}" />
```

The image is showing in the LWC but when I add width and height to the image it disappears. How can I add width and height and how I can add css in LWC.

Comment: Hi. Can you share how are you adding the width and height to the image (the exact code that you are using)?

Comment: I got this. I added a inline style to the img tag and it worked. But I am unable to add <style type="text/css"> in my lightning component.

Comment: <style> tag is not the way to include styles in a LWC. If you want to include your own styles in a LWC, in your component folder create a .css next to the .js and the .html and put your own styling there. Then, you can reference it in your .html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add inline css as below and update the height and width of your image according to your requirement.